Integral involving log sin and sinh
I would like to know if it is possible to compute the following integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\sin^2(\pi x)+p\right)\cos(2\pi nx)dx,$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N},$ $p=\sinh^2(a)$ and $a>0.$
For $p=0$ and/or $n=0$, I already know how to compute it.

Using only CAS like Mathematica:
$$\int_0^1 \log \left(\sin ^2(\pi  x)+p\right) \cos (2 \pi  n x) \, dx=-\frac{\left(1+2 p-2 \sqrt{p (1+p)}\right)^n}{n}$$
$$\int_0^1 \log \left(\sin ^2(\pi  x)+p\right) \cos (n x) \, dx=\\\frac{\log (p) \sin (n)}{n}+\frac{\cos \left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \,
   _3F_2\left(1,1,\frac{3}{2};2-\frac{n}{2 \pi },2+\frac{n}{2 \pi };-\frac{1}{p}\right)}{2 p \Gamma \left(\frac{-n+4 \pi }{2 \pi }\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+4
   \pi }{2 \pi }\right)}$$
